# What does it mean - "The flies gets to me"

Tags: british-english, slang

I often hear about this "The flies gets to me", what does it mean? As far as I reckon this is British slang.

Comment: "Gets" looks like an error: I would expect "get to me".

Answer (score 2):

It's not really a slang, *"get to"* is a phrasal verb

> **get to**
>   *phrasal verb of get*
>
> 1. annoy or upset (someone) by persistent action.

Thus, the sentence means the flies annoy you.